# validate the input

Tags: c

Part of the code is as follows but not work

```
  printf("Enter a line of text (Enter to stop): ");
  fflush(stdin);
  fgets(input, 256, stdin);

  if (input == '\0') {
    exit(0);
  }

  .....
  .....
```

i want if the user only press enter, the program will be terminated. how to do it?
thanks

Comment: fflush(stdin)? That's totally undefined behavior, since fflush() is meant only for output streams. I think you meant fflush(stdout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if(*input == '\n')` - if `fgets` reads a newline, it's stored in the buffer.